# $f^{-1}(V)=U$ imply $V=f(U)$ if $V\subset f(X)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Let $X,Y$ be topological space. Suppose  $f: X\rightarrow Y$ and $V\subset f(X)$, if $f^{-1}(V)=U$, is it true that $V=f(U)$?

---

I encounter this question when studying quotient topology, I think the answer is yes but I am not sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $U \subseteq X$.

the inverse image (or preimage) is defined as follows:
$x \in U$ iff $f(x) \in V$.

$f(U) \subseteq V$ by definition, since $f(u) \in V$ for all $u \in U$.

We show that $V \subseteq f(U)$. Suppose not. then there is some $v \in V$ so that there does not exist some $u \in U$ s.t $f(u) \in V$. But $V \subseteq f(X)$, so by definition there is some $x \in X$ s.t $f(x)=v$. But then $x \in U$ by definition, and we have a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Let $y \in f(U)$. Then there exists $x \in U$ such that $f(x) = y$ and since $U = f^{-1}(V)$, $x \in f^{-1}(V) \implies y = f(x) \in V$. So $f(U) \subset V$.

Let $v \in V$. Since $V \subset f(X)$, there exists $x \in X$ such that $v = f(x) \implies f(x) \in V \implies x \in f^{-1}(V) = U$, which shows $v \in f(U)$. So we have $V \subset f(U)$.

Answer (score 0):

True for any function $f$ and with $V\subset X.$

(1). If $v\in V$ then $\exists x\in X$ with $f(x)=v$ because  $V\subset f(X).$ So $x\in f^{-1}V=U$ by def'n of $f^{-1}V,$ so $v=f(x)\in f(U).$

(2).If $v\in f(U)=f(f_{-1}V)$ then $\exists y\in f^{-1}V$ with $f(y)=p.$ But $y\in f{-1}V$ implies $f(y)\in V$ by def'n of $f^{-1}V$,  so  $p=f(y)\in V.$

(3). By (1) we have $V\subset f(U).$ By (2) we have $f(U)\subset V.$

(4). Remarks .Note that (2):$f(f^{-1}V)\subset V$ always holds because $f(f^{-1}V)=\{p\in V:\exists x\;(f(x)=p)\}.$ Note that topology is irrelevant to the Q. It is a Q about  functions and sets.